# Reload TableView data from UItableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an IBaction in my subclass of UITableviewcell, and I am having difficulties to make it reload the data of the tableview. It looks simple, but I tried lot of staff and nothing was working.

Following, the code I am using in my UITableviewcell, but nothing reload:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)deleterow:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete content ?"
                                                      message:@"Do you want to delete ?"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Eliminar", nil];
    [message show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Eliminar"])
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);        
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];        
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datatesting.plist"];
        libraryContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [libraryContent removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"delete the Row:%@",libraryContent);
        [libraryContent writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

        UITableView *parentTable = (UITableView *)self.superview;
        [parentTable reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
 }

 @end
```

What is the best way to reload data from an UITableviewcell ?

Comment: "Also doesn´t work." - This doesn't help us at all. What happens? Nothing? How are you calling it? Are you sure that the method you are doing this in is even being called?

Comment: Hi sosbom, I just updated and add the content of my subclass, thanks

Comment: For deleting a simple row from the `UITableView` it is a more elegant solution to use the `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method instead of the full reloading. I can provide working code for it, if you need.

Comment: Holex, that looks a great idea, but it is your code for a UITableviewCell subclass ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure how your code is connected, but typically for things like this, you should use a delegate pattern by either passing a reference of your tableview into a property of your subclass:

```
subclass *s = [subclass alloc] init];
s.table = self.tableview;
```

then when you want to reference the parent table do so this way:

```
[self.table reloadData];
```

or by using a protocol/delegate combo which would really be the preferred approach.  Like this:

in subclass:

```
@protocol subclassdelegate <NSObject>
- (void)refreshParentTableView;
@end
```

set delegate in interface

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<subclassdelegate> delegate;
```

then call it when you need it like this

```
[self.delegate refreshParentTableView];
```

now, in the parent you need to do a couple of things
call your subclass and set self as the delegate property

```
subclass *s = [subclass alloc] init];
s.delegate = self;
```

then in the parent class implement the method defined in the protocol

```
- (void)refreshParentTableView {
     [self.tableview reloadData]
}
```

both approaches work, but I'd advise you to use the protocol approach.  It's mode code, but much easier to understand and probably more reliable.

be well.